# What letter is ム?

Tags: text, typography, character

[image]

Does anyone know what letter this is? I have been trying to figure out what letter this is. I don't even know if its a letter and I don't know if its in a different language and font. It looks like this, ム (like a triangle). I tried looking it up but I couldn't find any pictures that match what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi Benny, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. I took the liberty to edit your post to make it a bit more legible and clearer. If I butchered anything beyond recognition, feel free to [edit] it back. If you have any questions about this site or about Stack Exchange in general, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [help]. Do stick around and have fun!

Comment: You may be able to get clues about various symbols from this unicode tables website, too!
https://unicode-table.com/en/

Answer (score 10):

This is a katakana `mu`. Katakana is one of three Japanese scripts in use. It is used for loanwords, to convey a similar feel to ALL CAPS, or for onomatopoeia.

[image]

[Wikipedia article on the `mu` in both katakana and hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(kana)).

Comment: And for sound symbolism, lest we forget. :-)

Comment: @BennyPinkhasov, please remember to accept the answer so Vincent can get his points.